# Create subdirectory alias/rewrite to remove the final directory of a url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have an application with its UI accessible at `subdomain.example.com/subdir1/subdir2/` and would like for this to load for a user who goes to `subdomain.example.com/subdir1/`. I believe this is called a subdirectory alias, but I am not entirely certain about this. When I search for other questions/examples here, all I can find are explanations of how to 'hide' `subdir1` or `subdir1/subdir2` and I have been unable to figure out how to change those examples to work for my case.

The file structure is

subdomain root

- public_html
- subdir1

  - (a bunch of application folders and files)
  - subdir2

    - (a bunch of UI-related application files)
    - .htaccess

The `.htaccess` file in `subdir2/` contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase #add base url ex: www.website.com[/this part is your base url for this file up to "public"]
        #RewriteBase /your_base_url

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There are no other `.htaccess` files at the moment.

How would I go about having someone who visits URL `subdomain.example.com/subdir1` to load the content of `...subdir1/subdir2` (while the address bar URL remains `...subdir1`)? Is it possible from within this one .htaccess file, or will I need to create another one at some other location?